I need to merge 2 Echo audiofire 12's as 1 24 channel I/O in alsa not jack
Ubuntu studio controls allows for merging/adding extra sound cards through Jack. I have two Echo audiofire 12 units synced via word clock, so no drift between units. I don't use jack, only alsa how do i merge the two under alsa only, to provide a single 24 I/O for Ardour/Harrison mixbus.

You've not provided any Ubuntu release details; as Ubuntu Studio doesn't use JACK anymore (but it still can be used if users prefer it; there is no need of it with Pipewire), so are you asking about an older release?? It's helpful if you tell us as software stack details vary on release & you've not told us what you're using.
